# Draw raw-image into canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, image

I want to put an uploaded image into a canvas and work with it.

HTML:

```
<h2>Upload:</h2>
<input type="file" id="take-picture" accept="image/*">

<h2>Preview:</h2>
<p>
    <canvas id="show-picture" style="background-color: aqua; height: 100px; width: 100px;" />
</p>
```

Here is my javascript that handles the picture after upload:

```
    takePicture.onchange = function (event) {
        var files = event.target.files,
            file;
        if (files && files.length > 0) {
            file = files[0];
            processImage(file);
        }
    };
```

Now in the processImage-method the picture should be stored within a canvas.

```
function processImage(file) {
    // showImage(showPicture, file); //loading into a regular img-tag

    var canvas = document.getElementById('show-picture');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(file, 100, 100);
}
```

I was able to put this file into an img-tag but I can't simply draw it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawImage function takes an img element as input, not a file.

So you need to create an img element from the file (but you don't need to append it to the document). And when the image has finished loading (there's an onload event), you can draw it on the canvas.

**EDIT:** You also need to read the content of the file as a data url before setting it as the image src.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataUrl(file)
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
       context.drawImage(img, 100,100)
    }
    img.src = e.target.result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

had to sort something like this out myself, here is how i did it

read the raw image data same as what Philippe Mongeau did

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(dataURItoBlob(rawImageData));
reader.onload = function (e)
{
    // load the data as an image to draw it into the canvas
    var img    = new Image();
    img.onload = function ()
    {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src    = e.target.result;
};

function dataURItoBlob (dataURL)
{
    var onlyData = dataURL.substring(dataURL.indexOf(',') + 1);
    var decoded  = atob(onlyData);
    var dl       = decoded.length;
    var buffer   = new Uint8Array(dl);

    for (var i = 0; i < dl; i++) buffer[i] = decoded.charCodeAt(i);

    return new Blob([buffer], {type: 'image/png'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the FileReader + Image resulting in two callbacks.
Reading it as DataURL (base64) takes up more memory/cpu and will slow things down.

It's enough to just create a ObjectURL

```
var img = new Image
img.onload = function() {
   context.drawImage(img, 100,100)
}
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function loadImage() {
            var ctx = getCanvas('testCanvas').getContext('2d'); // get Canvas context
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'imgs/test.png';
            img.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200, 300, 200); // x, y, width, height
            }
        }
```

Comment: But I don't have any image source

Comment: If you can connect to that image by http://yourhost/path-to-image, you can use it in javascript as...... var img = new Iamge(); img.src='http://yourhost/path-to-image'; img.onload = ......